# How to explain more impressions and less ranking in Google search console? But I get really good leads when that happens

Tags: google-search-console, high-traffic

I see a similar trend for some of my keywords as the one in post [How do you explain more impressions and less ranking in Google search console?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106908/how-do-you-explain-more-impressions-and-less-ranking-in-google-search-console)

The problem is when the trend happens I get really good leads and good business for my law firm. Does anyone ever found an answer?

[image]

Comment: @nicolas-guérinet

Comment: @ricardo-mejias